# Using column names within an ifelse statement in dplyr mutate function

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm  trying to add an extra column to my dataframe based on the values in another column. I want a new column called Centre_label which will have the value "multiple" if Centre_count is more than 1, and take the same value as the Centre column if Centre_count is equal to 1.

My data currently looks like this:

```
        Partner    Centre Centre_count
1       A       Stockholm            1
2       B       Stockholm            1
3       C       Stockholm            4
4       D       Stockholm            1
5       E       Oxford               1
8       F       Oxford               2
```

I've tried using a conditional statement inside a dplyr mutate:

```
test <- scat_data %>% ungroup() %>% mutate( Centre_label = ifelse(Centre_count==1, Centre, "Multiple"))
```

This seems to work but replaces the values for Centre with the levels of the factor:

```
        Partner    Centre Centre_count Centre_label
1       A       Stockholm            1            3
2       B       Stockholm            1            3
3       C       Stockholm            4   "Multiple"
4       D       Stockholm            1            3
5       E       Oxford               1            5
8       F       Oxford               2   "Multiple"
```

I don't really understand why this is happening. Is there a way I can show the factor labels instead?

Thanks

Comment: Try using `ifelse(Centre_count==1, as.character(Centre), "Multiple")`  The `factor` elemnts will be coerced to its numeric encoding.  So, one option would be to convert to `character` with `as.character`

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly!

Comment: @KathyrnPoole Thanks for the feedback.  Glad to know that it works.